# Show List of Account Records and sort them according to selected button value (Multiple button can be clicked or selected)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

I want to Show Records on the button Click Below `Code` is Working fine but i want to add Multiple button click check without Deselecting previous Button.

[image]

In the above Picture if i select Hot it will sort Account Records on the basis of Rating as shown below :

[image]

Now I want if i select `Warm` after clicking on `Hot` then the Output must be Combination of Account Records that has Rating `Hot or Warm.`

`**Application.app **`

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:Component />
</aura:application>
```

`**Component.cmp**`

```
<aura:component controller="App_Controller" >
    <aura:attribute name="masterList" type="Account[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="Rating" type="String" default="Rating" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="RatingPicklist" type="String[]" />

    <div class="slds-border_top">
        <div class="slds-p-top_medium">RATING</div>
        <ul class="category-list">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.RatingPicklist}" var="rating">
                <lightning:button label="{!rating}" onclick="{!c.handleRating}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

`**ComponentController.js**`

```
({
    handleRating : function (component, event, helper) {
        var ratings = event.getSource().get("v.label");
        var action = component.get("c.findOnButtonClick");
        action.setParams({
            "ratings": ratings
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.masterList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

`**Apex Controller**`

```
public class App_Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findOnButtonClick(String ratings) {
        List<Account> PickListVal = new List<Account>();
        if(ratings != null){
            return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Rating LIKE :ratings];
        }
        return PickListVal;
    }
}
```

I've already tried using `List` to store multiple Label so i can use them in `SOQL` but the result is coming as `HotWarmCold` if i click on all three button

Comment: i think for your use case you need to use `lightning:radioGroup` try this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example#lightningcomponentdemo:ExampleRadioButtonGroupRequired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below code to store current label of the button that is clicked and **sent List of String to Apex instead of String.** And it worked for me.

```
handleClick : function (component, event, helper) {
        var getOnClickEvent = event.getSource();
        var ratings = getOnClickEvent.get("v.label"); //or by value getOnClickEvent.get("v.value");
        var action = component.get("c.findOnButtonClick");

        if (getOnClickFromCMP.includes(ratings)) {
            for(var i = getOnClickFromCMP.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(getOnClickFromCMP[i] === ratings) {
                    getOnClickFromCMP.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        else{
            getOnClickFromCMP.push(ratings);
        }


        if(!getOnClickEvent.get("v.class").includes('active')) {
            getOnClickEvent.set("v.class",getOnClickEvent.get("v.class") + " active");
        } 
        else{
            getOnClickEvent.set("v.class", "");
        }

        action.setParams({
            "ratings": getOnClickFromCMP
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.masterList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```